# How do I add ggplot trace to an existing plotly plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have an existing plotly chart from a reactive data source data() with $date (posixct)

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
  plot_data <- data()
  fig <- plot_ly(data = plot_data, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')%>%
         add_trace(x = ~ date, y = ~ pm_cor_A, name = "Trace A")%>%
         add_trace(x = ~ date, y = ~ pm_cor_B, name = "Trace B")%>%
```

I have created a ggplot that I want to add to my existing plot, that uses a different reactive data source datawx() with $obsTime (posixct) to make a stick plot:

```
datawx_df <- datawx()
  
  ggplot(data = datawx_df, aes(x = obsTime, y = 35)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_segment(data = datawx_df,
                 aes(x = obsTime,
                     y = 35,
                     xend = obsTime + lubridate::dhours(wspd * 1 * cos((90-wdir) / 360 * 2 * pi)),
                     yend = 35+wspd * 1 * sin((90-wdir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                     colour=wspd),
                     arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm"))) +
                     scale_colour_gradient(low="green", high="red")
```

I'm not sure how to add that as a trace to my existing plot, I tried this:

```
    datawx_df <- datawx()

   p <- ggplot(data = datawx_df, aes(x = obsTime, y = 35)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_segment(data = datawx_df,
                   aes(x = obsTime,
                       y = 35,
                       xend = obsTime + lubridate::dhours(wspd * 1 * cos((90-wdir) / 360 * 2 * pi)),
                       yend = 35+wspd * 1 * sin((90-wdir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                       colour=wspd),
                       arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm"))) +
                       scale_colour_gradient(low="green", high="red")
 plotly_fig <- ggplotly(p)
 
 fig <- fig %>% 
   add_trace(
   data = plotly_fig$data[[1]],
   type = "scatter",
   mode = "lines",
   name = "Wind Direction")
```

But nothing gets added to the plot. I'm guessing my logic is messed up somewhere...

Comment: Are all the code snippets part of the same renderplotly function in a Shiny application?

Comment: Yes they are in the renderplotly